# SQL Union two tables without relation and return separate columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to tables 'Table1, Table2' which are not related at all, but I need to do a common query with both because a filter.

I thought about this solution:

```
select * from(
 select t1.idT1 from Table1 t1 where idT1 = 1
 union all
 select t2.idT2 from Table2 t2 where idT2  = 1) as results
```

but it returns me a single column named idT1 and what I need is two separated columns: 'idT1', 'idT2' because I need to know if id is from table 1 or table 2 to look for their details later.

Is it possible?

Comment: Add a 't1'/'t2'literal to each select.

Comment: won't the above just return 1's?

Comment: It says "invalid column name" if I do that. Also I tried with * in both select but my tables doesn't have same columns number

Comment: It returns two rows with 1 because in this case I have id 1 in both tables. Thing is that this is a query for a filter so I need to know from which table is the ID returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from(
 select t1.idT1, null as IdT2 from Table1 t1 where idT1 = 1
 union all
 select null as idT2, t2.idT2 from Table2 t2 where idT2  = 1) as results
```

or as @jarlh suggested

```
select * from(
 select 't1' as T1OrT2, t1.idT1 from Table1 t1 where idT1 = 1
 union all
 select 't2' as T1OrT2, t2.idT2 from Table2 t2 where idT2  = 1) as results
```

I am assuming that where IdT1=1 in your question is just an example, because if it is really that then the result will be all 1s, as @Nathan_Sav pointed out.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Yes, it is an example for simplicity. in real life this is a dinamyc query for filtering purpouses but what i need was to know which with column id I was working so I simplified my problem for a better reading.